# Java Webhook Listener

Tags: java, php, webhooks

So I need to use webhooks for a project, baysically I have a website that is php
and when a user presses a button I want my java end to pick up a json response.

I understand webhooks to be the best way to do this but have only ever used webhooks that
are provided by a service like discord or slack, so have no clue where to start with my own
java based webhook service?

I am also open to other ideas the problem I am trying to solve is
I have a html/php site that needs to stay that way but when a user
pushes a button to submit a form that needs to do things on a java
app that is on a diffrent server and not linked in anyway to the site.

I did think about pooling a SQL table that just contains that data but
Webhooks seem the best way I think?

It is worth noting I am a script kid who is just trying to make my way through
a project and learn something new in the process